# отбросить подряд идущие цифры

Tags: python, pandas

Есть данные в столбце num.

Нужно отбросить подряд, идущие 9.

| num | prefix |
| --- | --- |
| 0312999 | 0312 |
| 589999 | 58 |
| 245999 | 245 |

Comment: опечатка, удаляются все 9

Comment: Так удаляются _все 9_ в колонке, или _9_ в конце числа?  Какой должен быть результат для значения `199299`: `1992` или `12`?

Answer (score 3):

Первое что приходит в голову — использовать [regex](/questions/tagged/regex), но возможно есть более элегантное решение.

```python
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard()

df['num'] = df['num'].astype("string").str.replace('9+', '').astype(int)
print(df)
```

###### Вывод:

```
   num  prefix
0  312     312
1   58     589
2  245     245
```

Comment: `.str.rstrip` еще